# What is the meaning of a $1\leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k \leq n$ index counter in Summation notation?

Tags: summation, notation

Whilst looking at the Vieta's formula on [brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/vietas-formula/#vietas-formula-higher-degrees), I found the following:

> Let $P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$ be a polynomial with
> complex coefficients and degree $n$, having complex roots $r_n, r_{n-1}, \ldots, r_1$.
>
> Then for any integer $0 \leq k \leq n$,
>
> $$\sum\limits_{1\leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k \leq n} r_{i_1}r_{i_2}\cdots r_{i_k} = (-1)^k \frac{a_{n-k}}{a_n}.\ _\square$$

What is the meaning of the $1\leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k \leq n$ notation in the index counter?

It seems to me, the notation is trying to generalise to all cases of $k$, but I'm not sure what the notation is telling me to do.
​

Comment: A choice of $k$ numbers between $1$ and $n$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay, numbers that also have to be in order I guess? Would that make all permutations of numbers permissible? Say, $k = 5$ and $n =10$, would the sum include $r_1 r_3 r_8 r_9 r_{10}$?

Comment: @TonyK Okay! So the notation does indicate order! Thank you. How would one change the notation to remove order, so you could include all permutations, for example $bac$?

Comment: $i_1, \ldots, i_k \in \{ 1,2,\ldots n \}$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you! One final question, what does the $\square$ notation at the end mean?

Comment: "end of the proof". See [Tombstone (typography)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(typography))

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Why did they choose to multiply the final part of the proof by the square? Is that common, or is the dot at the end similar to a full stop at the end of a sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just all possible combinations of $k$ distinct roots. For instance if $n=5$ and the roots are $a,b,c,d,e$, then for $k=3$ we get $$abc+abd+abe+acd+ace+ade+bcd+bce+bde+cde$$

Comment: But $k$ distinct roots in order. How would the notation change to include all permutations?

Comment: @Connor, when you multiply numbers together, the order doesn't matter!

Comment: True! But does that mean such notation is useless in all cases, or does it sometimes happen? For example could I write the following:
$$\sum_{1\leq \{i_1, i_2, \cdots, i_k\} \leq n}{r_{i_1}r_{i_2}\cdots r_{i_k}}$$

Comment: That notation implies that the $i_j$'s can be equal, in which case the sum is simply equal to $\left(\sum_{i=1}^nr_i\right)^k$. I don't know of a standard notation for when the $i_j$'s have to be distinct; you might write it as "$\sum_{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k}r_{i_1}r_{i_2}\cdots r_{i_k}$, where the $i_j$ are all distinct." Perhaps somebody has a better idea.